# ¿Cómo crear un degradado a un texto de derecha a izquierda en CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ya hice uno, pero lo hace de abajo hacia arriba, y lo que deseo es que el degrade al texto no al fondo que vaya de derecha a izquierda.
 Intente con esto:

```
h1{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d87602, #d64322);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Espera, creo que duplicaste tu pregunta anterior? Borra una de las dos por favor

Comment: Yo suelo usar esta herramienta y va muy bien [www.cssmatic.com/es/gradient-generator]

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar el degradado y luego la propiedad background-clip:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left,#6797bf,#ae39b6 100%);
-webkit-background-clip: text!important;
```